# How to load JavaScript files properly?

Tags: javascript, angular

I created an **index.html** file that looks like that:

```
<section id="slider" class="slider-element slider-parallax" style="background: url('assets/images/reyl/architecture-bank-bridge-417411.jpg'); background-size: cover;" data-height-xl="670" data-height-lg="500" data-height-md="400" data-height-sm="250" data-height-xs="200">
  <div class="slider-parallax-inner">
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="slider-caption slider-caption-center">
        <h2 data-animate="fadeInUp">
          <div class="text-rotater" data-separator="|" data-rotate="zoomIn" data-speed="10000">
            In Our <span class="t-rotate">Life|Family|Life|Home</span>
          </div>
        </h2>
        <p class="d-none d-sm-block" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="200">Le Magazine des collaborateurs du Groupe REYL, No 1 Décembre 2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<app-root></app-root>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
```

The `<app-root></app-root>` is calling a file called **home.component.html** in src/app/home/.

My slider (**#slider**) is working perfectly on this way, as well as all the functions defined in my `functions.js` file.

The problem comes when I try to move the `#slider` section from **index.html**, to **home.component.html**. When I do this, all functions defined in `functions.js` stop working (I keep getting errors about missing libraries, or the DOM elements are not found by my functions).

How am I supposed to fix this kind of issues?

Please find below the content of the function textRotator() (`functions.js`), which is supposed to animate the div **".text-rotater"**. It's not working when the 
**#slider** div is on **home.component.html**.

```
textRotater: function(){

  if( !$().Morphext ) {
    console.log('textRotater: Morphext not Defined.');
    return true;
  }

  console.log('textRotater()');
  console.log('$textRotaterEl');
  console.log($textRotaterEl);
  console.log('$textRotaterEl.length');
  console.log($textRotaterEl.length);

  if( $textRotaterEl.length > 0 ){
    $textRotaterEl.each(function(){
      var element = $(this),
        trRotate = $(this).attr('data-rotate'),
        trSpeed = $(this).attr('data-speed'),
        trSeparator = $(this).attr('data-separator');

      if( !trRotate ) { trRotate = "fade"; }
      if( !trSpeed ) { trSpeed = 1200; }
      if( !trSeparator ) { trSeparator = ","; }

      var tRotater = $(this).find('.t-rotate');

      var pluginData = tRotater.Morphext({
        animation: trRotate,
        separator: trSeparator,
        speed: Number(trSpeed)
      });

      console.log( pluginData );
    });
  }
},
```

The variables are defined at the end of `functions.js` file

```
var $window = $(window),
  $body = $('body'),
  $wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
  $header = $('#header'),
  $headerWrap = $('#header-wrap'),
  $content = $('#content'),
  $footer = $('#footer'),
  windowWidth = $window.width(),
  $portfolio = $('.portfolio'),
  $shop = $('.shop'),
  $gridContainer = $('.grid-container'),
  $slider = $('#slider'),
  $sliderParallaxEl = $('.slider-parallax'),
  $sliderElement = $('.slider-element'),
  $textRotaterEl = $('.text-rotater'),
  $cookieNotification = $('#cookie-notification');
(...)
```

And functions are supposed to be called when DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready( SEMICOLON.documentOnReady.init );
$window.on( 'load', SEMICOLON.documentOnLoad.init );
$window.on( 'resize', SEMICOLON.documentOnResize.init );
```

Comment: Can you please add your JS code as well?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, the whole file (3820 lines) or my function?

Comment: Please add the function only where you are binding the event to `#slider`

Comment: Did you properly check that your DOM was ready before calling your function ?

Comment: @rguerin, Yes the functions are called when DOM is ready

Comment: @118218 - With this you will always need all the elements to be available when the `functions.js` is executed. I think you need to either place safe check wherever you are using them or you should change the approach of how you handle references to DOM elements. I would recommend to change the approach.

Comment: @118218 What version of angular do you use?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, Do you think the DOM is not ready yet when I do $(document).ready( SEMICOLON.documentOnReady.init)? I don't see why it works when code is in 'index.html' and is stops working when in 'home.component.html'

Comment: @mpasko256, last one (7.0.0)

Comment: when in index.html - elements are there and then the js is executed. when in component - index.html is there - elements are missing - dom is ready - functions.js is executed -  angular triggers - gets template - elements are here. This is the difference

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, OK then how can I ensure all components (and then the DOM) are ready so I can init my functions?

Comment: @118218 Suppose something like this could help: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: I dont think you should even do it like this. Access the elements directly in the js. Ideally, if you are using angular framework, try and leverage it. It provides all sort of events, etc.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, Yes I know it's not the best way to proceed, but we need to integrate a multi-purpose theme on Angular for a quick release in some days. I will then translate all JS feature to TS, step by step.

Comment: Then do not create variables upfront, add your functions in AfterViewInit as specified by mpasko256.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, Yeah I will start by translating the textRotater() function and will post my solution there then. Thank you for the help

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, do you know how to translate "$textRotaterEl = $('.text-rotater')" in pure TypeScript?